# Is it possible that priests in the early Christian community were called father before Jesus said call no man father

Tags: historical-criticism

> Matt 23:9 - And do not call anyone on earth your father, for you have
> one Father, who is in heaven.

I am aware of the standard response to why Jesus said to call no man Father, that he was speaking figuratively.  However, it has occurred to me that a better fitting explanation would be if that verse was actually a later addition.  It seems odd that the only group in the world that calls some men Father (apart from actual fathers of children) has in their canon an order not to call any man father, which is also unique.   The custom precedes the Great Schism.  Priests in both the Orthodox and Catholic churches are called Father.

This could be explained better, I think, if the verse is a later addition that the writer put in Jesus's mouth as a response to early Christian communities who were beginning to call their priests Father.  Is there any reason (other than a belief in the literal inerrancy of the Bible) to think that is not a possibility?

Comment: You will need to provide some evidence that "Father" was used as a title in very early times.  I think it actually arose in early medieval times, not in antenicean times.  Further, by definition, there was no Christian community before Jesus!

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good reason that textual criticism of the Bible text is kept separate from theology - to avoid a "theological" text.  That is, the text should not be adjusted to fit theology, but theology must obey the text!

In the specific case of Matt 23:9, allow me to offer some general remarks about its "originality".  ALL textual critics consider this verse to be original for the following reasons:

- it is an integral part of the narrative beginning at V1, and ending with V36.  Therefore, if V9 is a late addition, then so is most of the chapter.
- Every early manuscript of Matthew contains Matt 23.
- There are some variations in the text of Matt 23 in the early MSS, but these variations only amount to variations in spelling and word order.  There is a dispute about the originality of the text of V14 (most early MSS omit the verse), but no such dispute exists over V9.
- Not only are the earliest MSS of Matthew in agreement that V9 is original, but the earliest church father who quote from this verse uniformly agree that it is original and quote from it as divinely inspired.

Thus, other than an uncomfortable theological irritation, there is no reason to doubt the originality of Matt 23:9.

**APPENDIX - "Father" as a title**

It is true that occasionally, apart from God having the formal title of "Father" some others received the title as well such as:

- Elijah was described by Elish as "father" in 2 Kings 2:13
- Elish also received the same title by Jehoash, 2 Kings 13:14
- Abraham is described as Israel's "father", John 8:39, 53, 56, Isa 51:2, Acts 7:2, Matt 3:9, Luke 3:9 (however, this is in a biological sense)
- Abraham is also described as "father" in Luke 16:24, 30, James 2:21, Rom 4:12, Gen 17:5

Answer (score 1):

Given the immediate context (Matt 23), Jesus appears to be prohibiting the use of titles (rabbi, father, teacher) either to distinguish oneself or one's associations. Further, 'Abba' was used by some to address prominent elders and probably religious instructors (cf. IVP New Testament Commentary). The thrust of the passage appears to be emphasizing our shared common brotherhood as God's children, in opposition to the human tendency to collect around the notables among us (a practice too commonly observed even in ecclesiastical circles where the term 'Father' is avoided). If that is correct (I am not aware of any argument against it), then this prohibition fits naturally in its context.

It may also be that Jesus was discouraging identity with Abraham as a sort of justification through lineage, as he addressed elsewhere (cf. John 8:31-ff).

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.